# Getting a row number in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to know if there are any methods to get a JavaFX TableView's row number.

for example I have a table that gets data within a text file with 10 rows and 3 columns, I want to have a listener that should be able to get the entire row and only get its row number.

```
 @FXML private TableView tableView;

 private void table() {

    TableColumn fn = new TableColumn("First Name");
    TableColumn ln = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    TableColumn age = new TableColumn("Age");

    fn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TextFileData, String>("First Name"));
    ln.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TextFileData, String>("Last Name"));
    age.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TextFileData, String>("Age"));

    tableView.setItems(dataFromTextFile);
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(fn,ln,age);
    ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
    selectedCells.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition > change) -> {
    //do something
    });
  }
```

in the line for

```
 ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
```

I tried changing `TablePosition` to TableRow but then I cannot use the addListener method. 
What I want is to be able to click an entire row and clicking that row would then output the rownumber of the position its on

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! 
turns out I can call setRowFactory to make a lambda and then create a new TableRow and have it set to a setOnMouseClicked event and all I had to do from there was just make `int rowNum = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex`!

Comment: sounds fishy .. without knowing what you are _really_ want to achieve, it's hard to tell whether or not it's a reasonable approach (might be, there are corner cases where mouseHandlers on the row are appropriate, but typically getting _TableView's row number_ is not one of these). Anyway, for your next question please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you are after and how it doesn't work as expected